# platform.js and analytics.js are getting blocked by AdBlocker

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-signin

In my webapp I am using two of google's `JavaScript-Library-clients`

1. https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js , for Google Analytics
2. https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js, for SignIn with Google
   But,both of them get blocked by `AdBlocker` or `Ghostry` plugins for browser.
   Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Did you manage to find a way around this?

Comment: Nope, I did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause**:

By design, adblockers/tracking blockers, block any calls going outside the domain.
So, if you load external libraries using their links, it will be blocked.

**Solution**:

Download these JS files and serve them from your servers and this issue should get resolved.